# Yii2, не устанавливается title страницы

Tags: php, html, yii2

Пытаюсь установить title во view, делаю это вот так

```
$this->title = $model->title;
```

Но почему-то он не выводится. Проверял исходный код страницы. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: возможно модель сейчас пустая и в ее title находится NULL

Comment: Попробуйте присвоить тайтлу тестовую строку. Если выведется тестовая строка то что то не так с моделью...

Comment: @perfect, проверял там есть данные -- строка

Comment: @lyhoshva, делал -- нулевой результат, всё так же

Comment: @Rumato значит инструкция $this->title = $model->title; находиться вне формы

Comment: Есть возможность что title присваивается после вашего определения тайтла

Comment: Так его в View нужно устанавливать я в доках где то читал, помню. Там так и было написано по view Для контролёрров там регистры использовать.

Comment: То раз. Два. У вас в моделе пустой титл. Добавте это `$this->title = 'Мой титл'`  а потом ещё и это   `var_dump($model->title;)`

Comment: Всё то что я написал засовывайте в вью и отпишитесь. Это не проблема, скорее всего.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за помощь! Дело было в том что в main view, не было вывода title, этот файл много раз редактировался и потом title был удалён. Я согласно дефолтному всё восстановил и сейчас всё работает.

Answer (score 2):

Если `$model->title` содержит строку и при этом она не выводится, то возможно в **layout**-е забыт вызов `$this->head()`. Эта функция «помечает» в html-шаблоне места, на которых должны потом выводиться мета-тэги во время рендеринга.

Вот пример использования:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Подробнее про все подобные функции «разметки» здесь: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#creating-layouts